# why proc exec result differs in various ubuntu systems?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

In my laptop with ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

when i do `sudo /proc/1/exe --version`
i get

```
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

But when i do the same command in docker container of image `ubuntu-upstart`

i get

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

And i have an ubuntu VM, inside which i have installed docker container of same image as i have mentioned above i get

```
exe (upstart 1.12.1)
Copyright (C) 2006-2014 Canonical Ltd., 2011 Scott James Remnant

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My question is why for the second case i get GNU bash result without the information about service manager, whether systemd or upstart

Answer (score 0):

The default docker init process (*entrypoint*) is defined in the Dockerfile; it need not be the same as the init process for the operating system the docker image is based on, if any. You can also run a different one without rebuilding the docker image using `docker run -it --entrypoint=bash`. (Technically, you also used to be able to do the same thing with the Linux kernel when booting up a real machine with a bootloader, using the `init=` kernel argument, although I don't think this is supported any more, at least on Fedora Linux, which is what I use.)

Sometimes Dockerfile writers use bash or a simple script as an entrypoint because they don't need the complexity that a supervisor like `supervisord` or `systemd` provide.